# What is the title of treasure hunting movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

Here are the facts I remember from the movie. It think it was from year 2009-2015.

1. A group was looking for treasure and they visited the granddaughter of the owner of the treasure to find some clues regarding its whereabouts.
2. They went to an island wherein they were interceped by pirates and threatened to find the treasure. A guy and the daughter accidentally fell in on a shipwreck wherein they discovered the missing treasure.
3. They rode a log that went straight to the ocean.
4. At the end of the movie they were all in a yacht celebrating. And they decided to throw the treasure in the ocean, since it wasn't theirs to begin with. And one of their desperate friends tried to save it and jumped into the ocean to recover some of the treasure in the water.

Comment: Hi! Do you remember the country\language? Where did you see it?

Comment: That's probably Jackie Chan's __[Chinese Zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CZ12)__ - In __[this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9n5OLPqRCtY)__ you can see some of the scenes you describe.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely [Chinese Zodiac](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1424310/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

You can watch the complete movie here:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2ip9pp

0:47:35: They fall into the chasm.

0:49:30: They stumble upon the shipwreck at the bottom of the chasm.

0:52:00: They find the gold in a tree trunk.

1:06:10: Starts the ride on the trunk.

1:09:18: Trunk ride ends with the trunk rocketing into the ocean.

1:14:50: Gold bullions are accidentally released from the towed trunk into the ocean.

Pirates (the one with the hook is not Johnny Depp:)):
[image]

Caught by the pirates:
[image]

Tree trunk rockets into the ocean:
[image]

Celebration on the yacht:
[image]

Salvage attempt after gold released into the ocean:
[image]